# HTML CSS Dropdown list scrollbar disappears

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ho2e8n4/

It works fine on jsfiddle.net, now the problem is as follows:

On hover on the child ol, it shows the dropdown list, which has a fixed height of 600% (so it will be the height of 6 parent li), and will hide the rest so you can scroll through them.

The problem i have on **all browsers**, is that when i move the mouse from the li to the scrollbar, the dropdown list hides (as if the "hover" event is no longer taking place). For some reason that doesn't happen on jsfiddle.net, but running it locally on Firefox, Chrome,IE,etc... it does.

How can i prevent the list from hidding when the mouse "hover" over the scrollbar?
As you can see:

```
overflow: hidden
```

and

```
overflow: auto
```

is being used, i don't know any other properties that would affect the scrollbar behaviour.

If this is not possible, then another option would be to hide the scrollbar but still be able to scroll with the mouse-wheel.

```css
.filterTabs{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}
.filterTabs ol{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}
.filterTabs ol a{
    background: none;
    color: rgb(70,130,180);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#first,#second{
  height:600%;
}
.filterTabs ol li{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.filterTabs ol li:hover{
    background:#ecf2f9
}
.filterTabs ol li ol li a:hover{
    background:#ecf2f9;
    color: rgb(70,130,180)
}
.filterTabs ol ol{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:rgb(70,130,180);
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #ecf2f9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.filterTabs ol ol li{
    float:none;
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    border:0px solid cornflowerblue;
}
.filterTabs ol ol a{
    color: #fff;
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}
.filterTabs ol ol ol{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}
.filterTabs ol li:hover > ol{
    display:block
}
.tab-content{
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class='filterTabs'>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <a>List▼</a>
         <ol id='first'>
            <li><a href=''>1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>4</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>5</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>6</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>7</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>8</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>9</a></li>
         </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <a>AnotherList▼</a>
         <ol id='second'>
            <li><a href=''>1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>4</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>5</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>6</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>7</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>8</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>9</a></li>
         </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It works on stackoverflow snippets, too

Comment: Since this works as is, there is something else in the code we can't see which make it not work, so my best bet is that you remove little by little from the full code until it does work. Doing that will let you know where to look.... and when you find it, and can't make it work, come back with it and we figure a way for you

Comment: the scrollbar works if you use the scroll in your mouse (in jsfiddle and also in browser/stackoverflow snippets). if you need to scroll down by click and drag on the scroll bar then i think you need to use div tags for implementing the dropdown. The current view that you have is as for as you can go by making use of ul/ol tags  @ndelucca

Comment: @divine I can click and drag the scroll bar without any problem on Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: @GerardReches i had to stop for a while with this issue due to some other problems in other webpages. I turned on the pc, opened the page, and it's working fine, on all browsers....... i didn't change any code, didn't update either the text editor nor the browsers, didn't update windows, anything... so if anyone has an idea of why... and what worries me is that since i didn't change the code, this could happen in reverse, someday, someone using the page turns on the pc and finds this bug... what would be a good course of action?